# Pdoc: doesn't generate documentation

Tags: python, documentation, documentation-generation, pdoc

I was trying to generate documentation for my python package using pdoc, and it didn't generate any documentation when I ran the command `py -m pdoc --html [package name].`It outputs the error `...\Python\Python38\python.exe: No module named pdoc.__main__; 'pdoc' is a package and cannot be directly executed` Why is this happening?

Comment: Fwiw, `python -m pdoc --help` works for me on Linux. There is [`pdoc.__main__`](https://github.com/pdoc3/pdoc/blob/77e62f97cfd03102ac8268f065501e94ab3335c3/pdoc/__main__.py) in the repo, assuming you mean [Pdoc3](https://pdoc3.github.io/pdoc/).

Comment: Yes, maybe the problem is only for Windows @K3---rnc?

Comment: Maybe Windows is the problem.  If you think it's a bug, raise an issue in the relevant issue tracker.

Comment: Same happens here: I'm using linux, and `python3 -m pdoc --html .` does not generate the output...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been fixed with the release of pdoc 1.0, here is the corresponding GitHub issue: https://github.com/mitmproxy/pdoc/issues/196